# PostgreSQL install error "unable to write inside temp environment variable path"

Tags: php, database, windows, postgresql, batch-file

I am installing PostgreSQL on Windows 7 64 .
I get the following error:

there has been an error. unable to write inside TEMP environment variable path

Everything I have found on the internet so far, i have tried. It includes:

Disabled all anti-virus software.

I have also stopped everything in the startup.

Checked file associations for .VBS scripts. Nothing irregular (Windows Script Host registered)

Windows Script Host is Enabled.

Changing the temporary folder on environment variables

I've tried installing as Administrator .

**What else can I try?**

Install log file:

[image]

Comment: I think you can find your answer in this [Thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224042/postgresql-9-install-on-windows-unable-to-write-inside-temp-environment-path)!

Comment: Thanks indeed!! after following your link I am now able to install it :)

Answer (score 0):

efore you start messing with the registry, check if WSH is actually disabled or not. To do that run wscript.exe in the DOS box.

If you see a dialog box called "Windows Script Host Settings", WSH is enabled, and your problem with PostgreSQL installation must be related to something else. If you get an error box that says "Windows Script Host access is disabled on this machine. Contact your administrator for details", WSH is disabled, and your problem with PostgreSQL installation may be related to it (or may be not).

For me, my problem was related to Windows script. I resolved this by right-clicking on smadav icon in the hidden icons in the task bar and checked "Allow Windows-script and Office-Macro (Permanent)". Then double click on the PostgreSQL setup again.